# how to store a link name in variable on another page

Tags: javascript, php

I have assigned a variable to store the link names when i click

```
echo "<a href ='details.php?id=".$row[0]."<br>'>".$row[0]."<br><br></a>";
```

so i can get the link name on next page by doing

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

the above code works fine on next page.

But i want to get the same id value on another page also. when i put the same code as above it doesn't work. so how do i get it. i have three page.

Comment: you send the id with method GET to the page details.php, then you find this variable $_GET['id'], just in this page, you want this variable in an onther page php ?

Comment: Can you show how did those files relate each other?

Comment: on next page do like `echo "<a href ='details.php?id=".$id."<br>'>".$id."<br><br></a>";`

Comment: you can use session if you are having some particular problem?

Comment: yes i want to get the id on details.php page and another page data.php page

Comment: @pkarthicbz; you can use the session: see the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get is just sent to the server ONCE. You need to store it. For example you could use sessions in php.

This stores the id.

```
<?php
session_start()
$_SESSION["id"]=$_GET["id"];
?>
```

Now you can access the id, until the user resets the browser...

```
<?php
session_start();
$id=$_SESSION['id'];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

page : details.php

```
<?php
  session_start(); //start session 
  if(!empty($_GET['id'])){
     $_SESSION["id"] = $_GET["id"]; //initialize the variable for using in data.php
     $id = $_GET["id"]; //for using in this page or you can just using $_SESSION["id"]
  }
?>
```

page : data.php

```
 <?php
   session_start();
   $id = $_SESSION['id']; //ready for use
 ?>
```